Questions I've asked since 2021 are not shown
I've asked numerous questions here on AskUbuntu, usually several per year, but my summary still doesn't show any questions since 2021? I just posted a question a few days ago but can't find it so I don't know if there are any answers.
Is there something I've done that hides them? Or is there something I'm supposed to switch on/off?
Thanks.

Did you look at page 2 in your profile under "Questions" and sort by newest activity?  I see posts going older than 2021. Additionally, I can see your deleted questions as a moderator and there's a number of your 'old' posts deleted that are from that time frame as well.  https://askubuntu.com/users/464356/jim-hitek?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=2 may be where to start looking

Page 2 on my screen shows even older posts of mine. Back to 2017 and covering to 2021 on page one. Only 2 pages shown as available. No newer posts. I've never purposely deleted any of my posts that I remember. Certainly not several years worth.

I can see newer questions in your summary, you're probably sort by Score instead of Newest (see the buttons above the questions in your summary).

Try sorting by "newest" instead and then go to the end of your list of questions.  That should show you the oldest questions you've posted that aren't deleted. (delelted is under "deleted questions", not sure if you see that)

Go to your profile's Questions page, sort by "Newest", and then go to the last page of the list of question pages on your profile.  You'll see your oldest posts that way.
